# vuejs use data from parent, but parent data usually update

Tags: vue.js

there are two .vue file and one is parent and another is child.

I am developing 'Sending file' function with Modal.

I will upload file data in parent.vue.
and when I click 'Send', child.vue will be popped up!
and I will choose, target who receive this file data.
and finally, I click 'Send' button, get connection to Backend server.

This is parent.vue

```
<<templete>>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'BillingView',
    components: {
        EmailSender
    },
    data() {
        return {
            uploaded_file: '',
            file_data: {},
            is_uploaded: false,
            popupVal: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendEmail() {
            if (this.is_uploaded == false) {
                alert('Upload your file');
            } else {
                << parsing file data>> 
                this.file_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.parsed_uploaded_file));
                this.popupVal = (this.popupVal) ? false : true
            }
        },
        popupClose: function ( value ) {
            this.popupVal = value
    }

    }
}
</script>
```

This is child.vue

```
<<templete>>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'EmailSender',
    props: {
        popupVal: Boolean,
        file_data: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {
                return {}
            }
        }
    },
    data: () => ({

    }),
    computed: {
        popUp: {
            get() {
                return this.popupVal
            },
        }
    },
    created() {
    },
    methods: {
        sendEmail() {
            let req_data = {};
            req_data ['file'] = file_data;

            axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_API + 'email/',
                {
                    req_data ,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8-sig'
                    }
                }
            ).then(res => {
                console.log('SEND EMAIL SUCCESS!!');
                console.log('SEND EMAIL RESPONSE::', res, typeof (res));
            })
                .catch(function () {
                    console.log('SEND EMAIL FAILURE!!');
                });
        }
    }
};

</script>
```

but here, "req_data ['file'] = file_data;" the file_data is empty, {}.

I expect when I update file_data in parent vue, child can know and use updated file data.

how can I do?

Comment: you forgot to use this keyword before accessing  "file_date".

Comment: you can try using $emit to pass the value parent to child https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure you send file_data as a prop to your component. e.g. Your component is 'myPopup' and you should use it as below to send file_data as a prop:

```
<myPopup :myData="file_data" >
```

In this case, you can get file_data as 'myData' in the child component as below

After changes, your props should be:

```
props: {
    myData: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => {
            return {}
        }
    }
},
```

Your function should be:

*Also, don't forget to use 'this' keyword. `this.myData` instead of `myData` in function.*

```
methods: {
    sendEmail() {
        let req_data = {};
        req_data['file'] = this.myData;
        
        // axios here
    };
},
```